# Show that $f(x) \le 2 \sqrt{(\varepsilon)} f(\frac{1}{\varepsilon} y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find a general condition under which $f(x) \le 2 \sqrt{(\varepsilon)} f(\frac{1}{\varepsilon} y)$  holds for $x<y$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Perhaps a condition on the derivative?!

Any help would be great.

Comment: to give you an answer we need to know something about $$f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume continuity on $f$.

We have condition

$$f(x)\leq 2\sqrt\varepsilon\, f\left(\frac y\varepsilon\right),\quad \forall y > x,\forall \varepsilon > 0\tag{1}$$

and by letting $\varepsilon = \frac 1 t$, we get equivalent condition

$$f(x)\sqrt t \leq 2f(ty),\quad \forall y>x,\forall t>0.\tag{2}$$

Let $(x_n)$ be strictly decreasing sequence such that $x_n\to x$. If we substitute $y = x_n$ into $(2)$ and take limit, by continuity of $f$ we get

$$f(x)\sqrt t\leq 2f(tx),\quad\forall t>0.\tag{3}$$

Take $t = 1$ to get $f(x)\leq 2f(x)$, which implies that $f(x)\geq 0$, for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Now, let $x = 0$ to get $f(0)\sqrt t \leq 2f(0)$, for all $t>0$, which implies $f(0) = 0$. Now, for any $x<0$, let $y = 0$ in $(2)$ to get $f(x)\leq 0$. This means that $f(x) = 0$, for all $x\leq 0$.

Hence, it is not loss of generality to assume $f\colon\Bbb R_{\geq 0}\to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, $f(0) = 0$.

Now, if there exists $C\geq 0$ such that $$C\sqrt x\leq f(x)\leq 2C\sqrt x,\tag{4}$$ then condition $(1)$ is satisfied:

$$2\sqrt\varepsilon\,f\left(\frac y\varepsilon\right)\geq 2C\sqrt y\geq 2C\sqrt x\geq f(x),\quad \forall y>x,\forall \varepsilon >0.$$

We will show that condition $(4)$ is necessary as well. For $x>0$, define $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}$. Since for $x = 0$, condition $(3)$ is immediately satisfied, we have that $(3)$ is equivalent to

$$g(x)\leq 2g(tx),\quad \forall x,t>0,$$

which is equivalent to $$g(x)\leq 2g(y),\quad \forall x,y>0,\tag{5}$$

or by symmetry $$\frac 12g(y)\leq g(x)\leq 2g(y),\quad\forall x,y>0.$$

Take any $y_0>0$ and let $C_0 = g(y_0)$.  We have $$\frac 12C_0\leq g(x)\leq 2C_0,\quad \forall x>0.$$ In particular, $g$ is bounded, and thus it makes sense to consider $S=\sup \{g(x)\mid x>0\}$ and $I=\inf \{g(x)\mid x>0\}$. If we show that $S\leq 2I$, we are done, since then we would have $I\leq g(x)\leq S = 2I$ and $I\geq 0$, i.e. $(4)$ would be true.

Choose sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $g(x_n)\to S$ and $g(y_n)\to I$. From $(5)$ we have $g(x_n)\leq 2g(y_n)$ and taking limit, we get $S\leq 2I$.

We conclude that continuous real functions on $\Bbb R$ that satisfy $(1)$ are precisely those that satisfy:

> $(i)$ $f(x) = 0$, $x<0$
>
> $(ii)$ $(\exists C\geq 0)\ C\sqrt x \leq f(x)\leq 2C\sqrt x$, $x\geq 0$

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful and detailed answer! This was exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I made a small mistake in my thoughts. So my actual problem is to find out wether, for all $x \le \varepsilon y, \varepsilon > 0$ it holds that $f(x) \le 2\sqrt{\varepsilon} f(y)$ where $f(x) = \sqrt{|x| \log{\frac{1}{|x|}}}$. Is this equivalent to my upper inequality and is it easier to prove it with the given function $f(x)$? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @nabla, normally, I'd vote for this question to be closed as off-topic, since it lacks proper details. It just happened that I found it interesting enough to give it a shot, even though I had to guess assumptions. What you are asking now is separate question, and I will not answer it here. Of course it is easier to answer the question for particular function, then classify functions for which the inequality holds, that should be obvious. But it looks to me that you haven't really tried to solve it yourself (which is another reason to close the question, but, oh well...).

Comment: My advice is that you ask another question with _all the necessary details_, such as details on $f$, proper quantification on variables, and most importantly - your attempt to solve the question. Otherwise, we will most likely just go back and forth here as you remember some new info you didn't mention (it happened to me before, and I should have been wiser this time, like Dr. Sonnhard Graubner).